# Event handler and function

Tags: javascript, function, handler

I'm new to Javascript programming, what is the different between an event handler and a function? Are they both same?

Comment: [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and [Event Handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) - Both taken from the MDN

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are functions that are called when an event is triggered.  So essentially the answer to your question is an event handler is a role that functions sometimes fill.

```
ele.addEventListener("click",function(){/*This function is your event handler*/}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

A function is a block of code that will be executed when "someone" calls it:

```
function functionname()
{
some code to be executed
}

function(); // calling the function
```

Events are code that execute JavaScript when something happens, such as pressing a button, moving your mouse over a link, submitting a form etc. The basic syntax of these event handlers is:

```
name_of_handler="JavaScript code here"
```

For example:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onClick="alert('hello!')">Google</a>
```